# How to properly use JSON.parse in this sample code (string to array)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to store an array in `StriptProperties` converting it to a string and recovering this way:

```
var personDataArr = ["Adam", "male", "programmer"];
function myFunction() {
  var personDataStr = JSON.stringify(personDataArr);
  ScriptProperties.setProperty('personData', personDataStr);
  var personData = ScriptProperties.getProperty('personData');
  personData = JSON.parse("[" + personData + "]");
  Logger.log("personData[0] = " + personData[0]);
}
```

But when I log `Logger.log("personData[0] = " + personData[0]);` I get `personData[0] = Adam,male,programmer`instead of `Adam`. Why? How to get, instead, the first element of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove square brackets ( `[]` ) from `JSON.parse` function:

```
personData = JSON.parse( personData );
```

This happens because you create multidimentional array ant it looks in final result as:

```
[["Adam", "male", "programmer"]]
```

This is why `0` index of that array return `Array` for you and not `Adam` value